# How can I refresh the contents of a control in a UIStackView?

Tags: ios, swift

In Swift 3 (XCode 8.3.3) I have a control in a UIStackView. I have an array of UIImageViews, and loop through the array to populate the stack view at run time:

```
for voiceIcon in voiceIcons {
    let voiceView = UIImageView(image: voiceIcon)
    addArrangedSubview(voiceView)
}
```

These icons will sometimes become disabled (replaced with a new image), so in order to update the control, I have a function to remove all the icons so that I can re-add the appropriate ones (if there's a better way, I'm listening!):

```
private func resetIconsView() {
    for subUIView in self.subviews as [UIView] {
        removeArrangedSubview(subUIView)
        subUIView.removeFromSuperview()
        print("Removing")
    }
}
```

I've also tried

```
for subUIView in self.subviews as! [UIImageView] { ... }
```

I get the debug line "Removing" for each of the icons, but they still remain in the control and the UI. I'm new to Swift, so I'm likely not understanding something, what approach should I take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your UIStackView only contains some UIImageView. You can iterate through all the arranged subviews of your stack view and update your image of that imageView.  A sample implementation could look like below:

```
func changeImage() {
    for view in self.arrangedSubviews {
        if let imgView = view as? UIImageView {
            imgView.image = UIImage(named: "taka_icon.png")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try code below:

```
for view in arrangedSubviews {
    view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it with an extension. You have also to remove Constraints if existing. Else this can cause some trouble.

USAGE: myStackView.removeAllArrangedSubviews()

```
public extension UIStackView {
    func removeAllArrangedSubviews() {

        let removedSubviews = arrangedSubviews.reduce([]) { (allSubviews, subview) -> [UIView] in
            self.removeArrangedSubview(subview)
            return allSubviews + [subview]
        }

        // Deactivate all constraints
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(removedSubviews.flatMap({ $0.constraints }))

        // Remove the views from self
        removedSubviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })
    }
}
```